# Arrested Development: Static on 3 Years, 5 Months & 2 Days in the Life Of

Tags: recording, rap, hip-hop, sound-quality

I have several copies of this album (CD, cassette, etc) and there is static on many of the tracks.

Back in '94 I remember hearing the explanation was: (some guy left the master LP in the sun, or something)

The explanation in parenthesis is mostly made up, but I do recall some drama happening to the master that resulted in these terrible recordings.

Back in the day, acoustic static was not "retro" or cool, it was a symptom of a shoddy job at making an album. It was in the news.

Does anyone have or recall the background story on what really happened?

[image]